# What is Jailing tx HASH?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, nodes

I participate in the testnet (I am a validator), and one of the tasks is to force myself to go to jail and write a timestamp, jailing block height and jailing tx HASH, but as far as I know there are no jail transactions on the blockchain. What does this mean? I will be glad to hear any ideas.

The task ends in a couple of hours, so I'll be glad if I get at least some answer.

Comment: I have no clue what you are talking about. Do you have a link or reference somewhere? Running a testnet validator just involves downloading and running some software...

Comment: @PieterWuille I know, it's just one of the tasks. There were also such tasks, for example: delegate, redelegate, undelegate :)

Comment: What network are you talking about? This doesn't sound related to Bitcoin.

Comment: I tried googling for some of the terms used in the question, and it looks like it may be about Cosmos. OP, that would be off-topic here.